# Websites for finding travel friends (with most members)?

Tags: online-resources, group-travel, travel-companions

I searched for some travel friends/buddies community websites. Which sites have the highest of number of members, nationalities, travel requests? Do they have mobile apps?

Comment: We use travel.stackexchange.com :D Welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately, the way you've phrased it, there are too many possible answers, and they'll be subjective.  I'd recommend hopping into the [chat] and asking there.

Comment: If you rephrases this to remove the opinion part ('sites you prefer') and concentrated on asking for a comparison of travel sites based on some hard metric (users, or price , etc) it might be narrow enough to be answered. Otherwise do as @MarkMayo says and head to chat.

Comment: Ok i edited the question

Comment: Hey I read your question, and if you were worrying about accomodation you could try Couchsurfing, and yes do use the chats.

Answer (score 4):

The main problem is these days, almost every big site tries to bill themselves as a community. In addition, many of them don't release stats on demographics, membership numbers and so on.

Some of the most popular ones include:

[Couchsurfing](https://www.couchsurfing.com/) - over [5.5 million members in 97,000 towns, in over 250 states or countries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CouchSurfing#Membership_and_site).

[TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.com/) claims to be the largest travel site in the world, but much of it is reviews, but there's over 60 million members.

Frankly, if you're adventurous, I'd suggest smaller community-oriented sites.  If you're a cyclist, [WarmShowers](https://www.warmshowers.org/) (35,000+ members) has made many of my cyclist traveller friends meet people, and frankly I'd be remiss if I didn't mention our own site - [Travel Stack Exchange](http://travel.stackexchange.com), where we currently have over 16,000 users - accumulated in under 4 years.  Many of us have met in person, and there's been at least a couple of meetups as well.

Speaking of which, [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com) is also great, if you specify 'travel' in your interests, you can find travellers nearby.  I'm going to one this week!

Answer (score 1):

I think Couchsurfing will be the best for that, they have a lot of forums and community groups. For sure you'll find travel buddies:)