# Which are my options to find trip companions online?

Tags: online-resources, travel-companions

I like independent trips so I avoid tours packages. But sometimes I need to find a trip companion or to make a small group in order to reduce expenses (i.e. rent a car) or to reduce risks (i.e. big trekking without guide).

The problem is that I can't find a website that join independent travellers. I use Couchsurfing website and ask in forums, so I'd like to know if there is any online resource specific for this topic.

NOTE: I've try to search "trip companion" in Google, but all first page results seems to take me to dating sites except the first one that takes to Lonely Planet forum.

Comment: related/duplicate: [Websites for finding travel friends (with most members)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38732/websites-for-finding-travel-friends-with-most-members)

Comment: related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35723/is-there-a-crowdsource-platform-for-trips

Comment: @Vince That question was closed because it asked for opinion. Anyway, I believe my question is more specific: I'm asking for a specific trip companion searching website, excluding forums and general travel sites (like this or CouchSurfing).

Answer (score 2):

I found one that might work, literally only on the past weekend. So good timing, potentially. And I'm aware of a more adventurous companion one too.

[Kicktraveler](http://www.kicktraveler.com/)  - the American spelling of traveler, but I'll let that pass - allows you to join or design trips that you want someone to come along with.  It's like crowdfunding your travels - say you want to join a trip in Egypt, but want others. Find someone who already has planned a trip who needs more in their group and join them, or start your own one, show an itinerary, costs, and then wait for the travel buddies to join in.

There are understandably a few commercial tours who have cleverly marketed theirs on there as well, but certainly it's a way to find companions for a specific trip.

On the other hand, if you're looking to do a more adventurous trip - bush hiking through the Amazon or a crazy adventure into the Antarctic, something like [Explorers Connect](http://explorersconnect.com/) might be more suitable - there are always some amazing adventures looking for trip partners (often with specific skills - doctors, drivers, photographers), or you  can propose one yourself.