# How do I find travel partners for a bicycle touring trip?

Tags: southeast-asia, bicycles, asia, travel-companions

I am looking for people interesting in going bicycle touring in S.E.Asia. Having travelled by bike before alone and with a partner, I'm keen this time to find someone likeminded to go through the process of preparing and be up for an adventure. Any websites, forums or otherwise for finding this kind of person?

Comment: Also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38732/websites-for-finding-travel-friends-with-most-members

Comment: And http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/35723/is-there-a-crowdfunding-platform-for-trips might be interesting

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because the OP is asking for bike touring companions.

Comment: just as a note, finding someone willing to go bicycle touring is a bit different to general sight seeing, hence the usefulness of the answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few sites aimed at bicycle tourers.  For example:

- http://www.crazyguyonabike.com/classifieds/ (the whole site is good, this is just where people post ads for companions).
- https://www.warmshowers.org/forums/general/looking-companions
- http://www.reddit.com/r/bicycletouring
- http://www.adventurecycling.org/adventure-cyclist/companions-wanted/
- http://www.togoparts.com/forum/index.php (Singapore-based, you might find English-speaking native Asians here)
- http://www.cyclingtouring.org (a specific site for finding cycle touring companions/buddies/friends. List your own cycle tour or join someone else)

You should always mention how many days, what countries, and what sort of pace you ride.  Mentioning those things here wouldn't hurt either.